# Let $Y\sim G$. Show $P(G(Y)\leq t)\leq t$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Y$ be a RV with cdf G. Let $G^{-1}$ Denote the quantile function of Y (or of G? I'm not sure about the terminology here).

My attempt;

$$P(G(Y)\leq t) \overset{*}{=} P(Y \leq G^{-1}(t))=G(G^{-1}(t))$$

I really feel like this is correct - the * is just the set equality;
$$\{y|F(y) \leq t\} = \{y|y \leq F^{-1}(t)\}$$
Which follows directly from the def. of the quantile function yeah?
I'm going crazy here - please help - since if this is right then I get the backwards result;

$P(G(y) \leq t) \geq t$

Comment: Doesn't your work show $P(G(Y) \le t) = t$?

Comment: I'm assuming your definition of the quantile function is the generalized inverse $G^{-1}(t) = \inf \{ x : G(x) \geq t  \}$? If so, both your first equality and your conclusion that $G\circ G^{-1}(t) = t$ are incorrect unless you have a proper inverse. It is actually only true that $G\circ G^{-1}(t) \geq t$ without additional assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the properties of quantile functions, we have $G^{-1}(t) \leq x$ if and only if $t \leq G(x)$. For standard uniform $U$, this implies $P(G^{-1}(U) \leq x) = P(U \leq G(x)) = G(x)$, so $G^{-1}(U)$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. Again by the properties of quantile functions, we have $G(G^{-1}(t)) \geq t$, so $G(G^{-1}(U)) \geq U$ almost surely. Conclude $$P(G(Y) \leq t) = P(G(G^{-1}(U)) \leq t) \leq P(U \leq t) = t.$$ Chapter 21 of van der Vaart's book on Asymptotic Statistics lists and proves the properties of generalized inverses I am using here, although I am sure many books on statistics lists these and related properties.

Comment: Ok I follow all of this, but I still can't really see where I went wrong. My first = is wrong then?

Comment: Isn't my firs = the same as your first sentence?

Comment: No, note that the inequalities in my argument go in the other direction.